# remove a child element br

Tags: javascript, html, element

I am working on a dynamic Checkbox where I can add and remove e.g. users. The adding is working fine, but to remove all the child elements troubles. Especially the br I don't know how to remove.

```
        <style>
    .container { align:right; border:1px solid #000000; width:300px; height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var addTask = function () {

      var newCheckbox = document.createElement("input");
      newCheckbox.type = "checkbox";
      newCheckbox.value = document.getElementById("MailAddress").value;
    newCheckbox.id = "C11";
      document.getElementById("UserList").appendChild(newCheckbox);


      var label = document.createElement('label');
      label.htmlFor = document.getElementById("MailAddress").value;
    label.id = "L11";
      label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("MailAddress").value));

      document.getElementById("UserList").appendChild(label);
      document.getElementById("L11").appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  }

  function delTask() {

        var item = document.getElementById("C11");
        item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
        var item = document.getElementById("L11");
        item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
      // How can I remove die <br> too?
  }
  </script>
    </head>
    <body>


    <header>
        <p>Usergroup:</p>
    </header>
    <input type="text" id="MailAddress">
    <input type="submit" value="Add Mail Address" onClick="addTask()" id="AddUser">

    <div  class="container" id="UserList"></div>

    <input type="submit" value="Delete One Mail" onClick="delTask()" id="remove">
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `document.getElementsByTagName('br')` to get the array of all `br tags` then you can remove the br tag you want to remove. This requires you to know how many `br` tags are there in your document beforehand so that you'll remove the one with the correct index.

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("br");
x[1].parentNode.removeChild(x[1]);
```

will delete the second `br` tag in the document, assuming you have two `br` tags to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If removing `<br>` is the issue, then try this

```
var e = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
 e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replace('<br>', '');
```

Comment: Seems to work, great and thanks! So the TagName("p"... does point to this BR ?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need - it looks for the elements with IDs and then removes every subsequent sibling node up to an element (or tag), as opposed to comment, text, etc.

```
  function delTask() {
        var el1 = document.getElementById("C11");
        var el2 = document.getElementById("L11");
        var next = el2.nextSibling;
        // create array to hold all the elements to be removed
        var items = [el1, el2, next];
        // iterate through siblings until a tag (here <br/>) is found
        while(next && next.nodeType != 1) {
            next = next.nextSibling;
            items.push(next);
        }
        // remove elements in reverse order
        while(var el = items.pop()){ el.parentNode.removeChild(el); }
        item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
  }
```

A few notes there: you should not use "var" with the same variable multiple times in one block. The IDs (C11, L11) should be parameters, not hardcoded values.